How to efficiently read HDF5 file using NetCDF-java
What is an efficient way to use the NetCDF-java API to read an HDF5 giving a raster variable consisting of a structure in the following form?
Structure {
  float depth;
  float uncertainty;
} values(2115, 1635);
:_ChunkSizes = 67U, 103U; // uint

In the past, I've had good luck using the NetCDF-java API to process simple raster Variables (see Reading NetCDF files). But when I attempt to access a Structure type, my code runs very slow.   Processing the data for the structure shown above requires 36 minutes to run. Processing the same file with the JHDF Java HDF library requires only about 2 seconds.  Clearly, I am not using the NetCDF-java API the way its authors intended. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any good examples for dealing with structure variables. I did read the Javadoc and Junit test cases from the project, but the best I could figure out is the code shown below.
I am using the current release of NetCDF-java, version 5.6.0. The sample file I tested is an IHO S-102 format (HDF5) file giving bottom depths for harbors. Sample files can be downloaded at NOAA S-102 Bathymetric Surface Data. I tested a number of files with similar results (the variable shown above is from 102US00_US4NJ1FH.h5). Although the code below loops on row and column, I also tried a variation that accessed grid cells based on the chunk size scheme.   Looking at the code, it’s obvious that the loop creates an awful lot of short-persistence objects, but I think the real problem is due to the underlying approach.  I'm pretty sure the code makes a distinct file access operation for each data value it retrieves. But I haven't been able to figure out a more efficient way to use the API.

    NetcdfFile ncfile = NetcdfFiles.open(targetFilePath);
    Variable v = ncfile.findVariable(targetVariableName);
    System.out.println(""+v.toString());
    Structure s = (Structure) v;
    v.setCaching(true);  // does not seem to make a difference
    int[] shape = s.getShape();
    StructureData sd = s.readStructure(0);
    Member m = sd.findMember("depth");
    double sumValid = 0;
    int nValid = 0;
    int nNoData = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < shape[0]; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < shape[1]; j++) {
        int index = i * shape[1] + j;
        sd = s.readStructure(index);
        float[] f = sd.getJavaArrayFloat(m);
        if (f[0] == 1000000) {
          nNoData++;
        } else {
          sumValid += f[0];
          nValid++;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("nValid:  " + nValid);
    System.out.println("nNoData: " + nNoData);
    System.out.println("Mean:    " + (sumValid / nValid));

Thanks in advance for your help.

You might try posting an issue or starting a discussion on the netCDF-Java repo on Github if you don't get anything helpful here on Stack. https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-java

Thanks for your excellent suggestion.  If I don't see anything here on stackoverflow in the next week or so, I will follow up on the Github site.
